# Possible to run Ubuntu just off a USB drive?

Tags: boot, usb

If I buy this [flash drive](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-turbo-plus-64gb-usb-3-0-flash-drive-silver-black/1876003.p?id=1219066202305&skuId=1876003) would I be able to run Ubuntu from it?

I broke my laptop port to put the harddrive in, and I've always wanted to run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you certainly can do that, though I wouldn't shell out big money for a hard drive from BestBuy -- I tend to use free ones that come from merch tables at conferences and the like.  See instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on how to do it on Windows, or grab an iso and use `dd`!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can, I would comment on your post if I had more reputation, but a few things to make sure

1. Make sure your laptop support USB 3.0, which the flash drive you linked to is
2. depending on how new your laptop is you might need to play around with UEFI, [here's a link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) to help out with that.
3. You said you broke the 'port thing'. Does that mean you busted your USB connector? Or does that mean you broke an internal connector? Or do you mean the CD drive? If you have broken the USB port you won't be able to use that flash drive.

Also, Welcome to Ubuntu! It's an awesome operating system and use Ask Ubuntu as a resource, make sure to search though before posting :)

Comment: The internal thing, is that even fixable lol?, thanks :)!

Comment: Is it the internal hard drive or CD Drive? Does your computer currently boot into Windows at all?